# jQuery Tabelize is not working when Locker Services is activated

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, jquery, locker-service

I am having an issue with using jQuery Tabelize when Locker Services are activated.When Locker services are deactivated code just works fine.

I have created sample code to reproduce the error.

**Component Code:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<ltng:require styles="/resource/JqueryTabelizer/tabelizer.min.css"/>
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/JQueryLatestLockerService/jquery-2.2.4.min.js,
                       /resource/JQueryLatestLockerService/jquery-ui.min.js,
                       /resource/JqueryTabelizer/jquery.tabelizer.min.js" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>


<aura:attribute name="isResourcesLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>


 <table id="demo" class="controller">
  <tr data-level="header" class="header">
    <td></td>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-level="1" id="level_1_a">
  <td>Level 1 A</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="2" id="level_2_a">
  <td>Level 2 A</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="3" id="level_3_a">
  <td>Level 3 A</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="3" id="level_3_b">
  <td>Level 3 B</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="4" id="level_4_c">
  <td>Level 4 C</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="4" id="level_4_d">
  <td>Level 4 D</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="4" id="level_4_e">
  <td>Level 4 E</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="1" id="level_1_b">
  <td>Level 1 B</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="2" id="level_2_b">
  <td>Level 2 B</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="3" id="level_3_c">
  <td>Level 3 C</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="4" id="level_4_h">
  <td>Level 4 H</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="4" id="level_4_i">
  <td>Level 4 I</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="4" id="level_4_j">
  <td>Level 4 J</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-level="3" id="level_3_d">
  <td>Level 3 D</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
  <td class="data">2</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller Code :**

```
({
  doInit: function(component,event,helper) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#demo').tabelize({

            onRowClick : self.rowClicker,

            //must be set before init
            fullRowClickable : true,

            // callbacks
            onBeforeRowClick : null,
            onAfterRowClick : null,
            onReady : null

        }); 
    });           
 }   
})
```

After activating locker services it throws error as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined throws
>   atresources/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/lockerservice/safeEval.html:84

Or it throws an error as "PrevRow is not defined".
Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you expect it to work? The list of ["known good" with Locker Service JavaScript libraries is quite small](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).

Comment: I am sure about the Jquery version I am using ( JQuery 2.2.4) is compliant with locker services but not sure about Tabelizer. Is there any way to know what works and what doesn't work with Locker services ?? We have many components which are using JQuery ,D3 and leaflet.

Comment: The only list I know is the one I linked to but there may be others. The problem might be a small thing that you could patch but you would need decent javaScript debugging skills to work that out.

Comment: Thanks for inputs Keith.I am trying to resolve it but no luck yet. Its seems ,post locker services activation  JQuery Tabelizer is not being loaded in Resource folder rather its being loaded in No Domain section( Debugger Source), I believe this is what causing error .

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you're using [this](https://github.com/powerconsulting/jquery.tabelizer) js library called jquery.tablizer. Looking at the source code, I can tell this lib is not LockerService compliant since it is not [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) compliant. The `$prevRow` error you're seeing is because in the libraries `init` function it tries to set `$prevRow` like so:

`$prevRow = null;` [source](https://github.com/powerconsulting/jquery.tabelizer/blob/master/jquery.tabelizer.js#L178)

`$prevRow` was not previously defined so in non-strict mode this would create a new global variable. In strict mode this throws an error.

There may be other violations in there as well but that's the most obvious. You could try manually attaching all global variables to the `window` object and see if that gets you further.